# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'c'

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, dataframe

```
project=pd.read_csv("train.csv",sep=',')
```

this dataset `train.csv` has 200column, named as var_0,var_1 ....... var_199

```
for i in range(200):
    c= "var_" + str(i)
```

the above line is for creating variable names using loop

```
    #print(c)
    b= project.c.describe()

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-b90b661d528b> in <module>
      2     c= "var_" + str(i)
      3     #print(c)
----> 4     b= project.c.describe()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5177             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5178                 return self[name]
-> 5179             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5180 
   5181     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'c'
```

Comment: you have object `c` in for, not attribute for df....

Answer (score 0):

You are calling it as if `c` was an attribute, while it is a column name; it should be:

```
project[c].describe()
```

and you don't need to assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues with your code.

**1st problem**
You overwrite the variable `c` in every loop your for does

```
for i in range(200):
    c= "var_" + str(i)

>> print(c)
>> "var_200"
```

What you want is:

```
c = ["var_" + str(i) for i in range(200)]
```

or

```
c = []
for i in range(200):
    c.append("var_" + str(i))
```

**2nd problem**
The `c` is a python variable. Not a column. What you need to do is to use it like this

```
project[c].describe()
```

What you did would work only if you had a dataframe with the column name "c". For example

```
    a    b    c
0   1    2    3
1   3    1    5
```

You would be able to use `project.c` and would print

```
    c
0   3
1   5
```